# How do I (cypher) query Neo4j embedded graph database from java program for Neo4j 3.x?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-java-api

Neo4j has grown a lot since I last used it (milestone 2.0 to 3.0). I wanted to use cypher from java program with embedded graph database (GraphDatabaseService).

I used to create an ExecutionEngine and go from there for this earlier.

It appears that now the preferred way is to use org.neo4j.driver.* for this purpose.

This bundle does not seem to be there in the libs I get from Neo4j 3.0.7.

Is there anyway I can execute cypher query for embedded graph database using java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GraphDatabaseService has execute(...) function to run cyphers. 
https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/GraphDatabaseService.html#execute-java.lang.String-

There are some examples on Neo4j's tutorial page.
http://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/#tutorials-java-embedded

Answer (score 1):

You can execute Cypher using the Java API for an embedded neo4j DB. Refer to [this section](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/#tutorials-cypher-java) of the 3.0 docs for more info on this.

The beginning of that same section of the docs shows [how to set up your development environment](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/#tutorials-java-embedded), including setting up the dependencies.